# Unity3d Помогите настроить colliders и rigidbodies

Tags: unity3d

Нужно что бы юниты в мире 2d не могли падать сквозь пол, но могли проходить сквозь друг друга.

Подскажите направление или варианты решения проблемы.

Comment: какую форму имеет пол и какие его свойства. Если к примеру пол - фиксированная плоскость и отскока нет, то можно сделать вообще без коллайдеров.  А так можно посмотреть в сторону слоёв.

Comment: Пол фиксирован. Отскока нет. Коллайдеры нужны для юнитов, например один юнит стреляет чем то из пушки во второго и пуля должна стригерется от коллайдер цели. Гляну что такое слои )

Comment: Благодарю, слои это именно то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Можно запретить юниту коллизию с другими юнитами, исключив из обработчика коллизий все объекты под определенным тегом. 
Данный скрипт должен быть на каждом юните. Тег "Robot" следует заменить на тег ваших юнитов.

```
function OnCollisionEnter (collision : Collision) 
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Robot") {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(collision.collider, collider);
    }

}
```

Подробнее тут:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ignore-collisions-by-tag-solved.60387/

Answer (score 0):

Разместите ваших юниты и пол в разных слоях Layers. Затем зайдите в `Edit / Project Settings / Physics2D` и снимите галочку в том слое который выбрали для юнитов, там где он пересекается строка и столбец сам с собой. Теперь ваши юниты не будут колизиться к друг другу, но при этом будут колизиться с другими объектами.